# Alternative way to unlock Facebook account to recognizing friends' photos

Tags: facebook

I moved to another country, and when I tried to log in to Facebook, my account was "temporarily locked". Now I need to recognize my friends from photos. Only that I have few hundred "friends", and also lot of images they upload are not actually photos of themselves. 
I tried few times to identify them, but I always got "Your answers weren't accurate enough." result.

Is there any other way to unlock my account? I never gave them my phone number, but I have my e-mail.

What ways do I have to prevent something like this in future? I know, that by giving my phone number I give them another way to prove my identity, but I'm not happy with sharing my phone no. with Facebook.

Can this check be disabled for future?

Comment: (in my best grandma voice): If you can't recognize their faces, are they REALLY your friends?

Answer (score 1):

As for preventing this issue in the future, I suggest turning on the [trusted contacts](https://www.facebook.com/help/119897751441086#What-are-trusted-contacts?-How-do-I-add-trusted-contacts-to-my-account?) feature.

> Trusted contacts are friends you can reach out to if you ever need help getting into your Facebook account (ex: you forget your Facebook password and can’t get into your email account to reset it).
>
> After you set up trusted contacts, next time you can't get into your account your trusted contacts can access special, one-time security codes from Facebook via a URL. You can then call your friends to get the security codes and use those codes to access your account.

Then, when you get locked out of your account, you can [use your trusted contacts to get back in](https://www.facebook.com/help/213343062033160):

> If you're locked out of your account, you can use trusted contacts to get access to your account. If you have trusted contacts set up:
>
> 1. Click Forgot your password? and find your account.
> 2. Follow the instructions to use your trusted contacts to get back into your account.
> 3. You'll receive a set of instructions that includes a URL. The URL contains a special security code that only your trusted contacts can access. Call your friends and give them the URL so that they can open the link and give the security code to you.
> 4. Use the security codes from your friends to access your account.